Defining majorization of vectors using doubly stochastic matrix
On Wikipedia, it says that given two non-increasing vectors $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $a$ majorizes $b$ if and only if there exist a doubly stochastic matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ such that $b=Da$.
While I was able to prove that if $a$ majorize $b$ there exists such $D$, I could not prove the inverse. Can someone help me prove that? or maybe that's a mistake in the Wikipedia article?
My proof
I proved the first part by induction on $d$.
For $d=1$, it is clear that $a=b$ and $D=1$.
Now, assuming the claim is true for $d=k - 1$ for some $k\ge 2$, we need to prove it for $d=k$.
Due to the majorization, $a_1\ge b_1 \ge b_k\ge a_k$. therefore, we define $\alpha:=\frac{b_1-a_k}{a_1-a_k}$ and the following matrix:
$$E:=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1-\alpha \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & 0 \\
1 - \alpha & 0 & \dots & 0 & \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We can show that $E$ is doubly stoachastic.
We define $b':=Ea$. It is possible to show that $b'$ majorizes $b$ and $b'_1=b_1$. Therefore, using the induction hypothesis, we can find a doubly stochastic matrix $F\in\mathbb{R}^{(k-1)\times (k-1)}$ such that:
$$b=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & F\end{pmatrix}b'$$
by defining $D:=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & F\end{pmatrix}E$, we prove the theorem (multiplying two doubly stoachstic matrices results in a doubly stochastic matrix)
Q.E.D.

See this post

Hi @BenGrossmann , thanks for the response!
While your proof on the other post looks solid, it does not prove what I wanted: I want to prove that if there's a doubly stochastic matrix $D$ such that $b=Da$ than $a$ majorizes $b$.
Do you know to point for a proof for that?

Oh, I misunderstood! That's actually the easier direction. I'll write up a proof here if I get the chance and no one beats me to it

The following proof is given in Bhatia's Matrix Analysis as part of the proof for Theorem II.1.9.
Let $A$ be doubly stochastic and let $y = Ax$. To prove that $y \prec x$, we may assume without loss of generality that the coordinates of both $x$ and $y$ are in decreasing order. For any $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k y_j = \sum_{j=1}^k \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}x_i.
$$
Denote $t_i = \sum_{j=1}^k a_{ij}$. Note that $0 \leq t_i \leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i = k$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^k y_j - \sum_{j=1}^k x_j &=
\sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i - \sum_{i=1}^k x_i
\\ & = 
\sum_{i=1}^n t_i x_i - \sum_{i=1}^k x_i + (k - \sum_{i=1}^n t_i)x_k
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^k (t_i - 1)(x_i - x_k) + \sum_{i=k+1}^n t_i(x_i - x_k) \leq 0.
\end{align}
It's easy to see that equality holds in the case that $k = n$. So, $y \prec x$.

If $Da=b$ with $D=(p_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq d} $ bistochastic then for fixed $1\leq k\leq d-1$, $c_j=\sum _{i=1}^kp_{ij}\leq 1$ for $j\leq d.$ Since $D$ is bistochastic we have  $ \sum_{j=1}^dc_d=k$. This implies that  we have $b_1+\cdots+b_k=\sum _{j=1}^dc_ja_j$ and therefore $$\sum _{j=1}^kb_j-\sum _{j=1}^ka_j=\sum_{j=1}^k(a_j-a_k)(c_j-1)+\sum_{j=k+1}^d(a_j-a_k)\geq 0.$$
This is from my notes, but I do not remember where its comes from.
